# Getting grey hash screen when using RDP into my server

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 - this is my first ever outing with Linux; this may well be a simple question.... :) (on a different note, i LOVE this apt-get stuff!)

I have installed the server and I wish to RDP into it from my windows machines.

I have read some tutorials and with a mixture of xRDP, VNC and some gnome thingy (gnome classic desktop gui i believe..)

I finally managed to get it to connect and I can see a nice interface.

I have also disabled the desktop interface from loading when the server itself reboots - used the config edits at the bottom of [this page](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html) to do that.

So - my question.

If i boot my server up I am prompted to login at the terminal command line. If I log in I can then successfully remote connect from my windows machines.

However, if i do not log in then when i RDP i just get a screen covered in grey hash's.

Is there a way I can set this up so that I don't need to log in on the server itself before being able to RDP in? I suppose I could disable my credentials on the server though that seems counter intuitive. Ultimately, should the server ever need rebooting via RDP I don't want to not be able to RDP back in all because the server hasn't had its credentials entered on reboot.

I hope this makes sense...

**Oh...also to mention..**
Because I had followed a bunch of different tutorials (some had parts that worked where other parts failed) it's likely that I have entered some command or other that perhaps disabled what would normally be a default behaviour - what I couldn't do though is tell you exactly what i have been typing...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok - so as it turns out, it DOES log in and provide the desktop if i haven't logged in locally - I just needed to wait...

It seems to take 20 or so seconds for the gui to fire up - rather than the couple of seconds if i'm already logged in locally.

All that's to say, it works out the box... :)